# send email using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send an email using the CodeIgniter framework and it's working for me, the problem that when I tried to insert my message into a view and loaded that view, identifying my message as this view, and when I checked the sent message it was an empty message... I wonder what's wrong:

```
 $data = array(

              'Message'=>       $message, 
              'SenderEmail'=>   $senderEmail,
              'SenderName'=>    $senderName, 
              'SenderImage'=>   $senderImage
            );

           $messageView = $this->load->view('user/SendEmail',$data);

           $params = array(
             'RecieverId'=>$recieverId,

             'Message'=> $messageView
           );
```

The message is received empty, can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

`$messageView = $this->load->view('user/SendEmail',$data, true);`

Which tells CodeIgniter to return the content of the view back as a return value, rather than output it to the browser ;)

Hope that helps.

Gavin

Comment: when i used True value the email is not even delivered, so rather than receiving a blank email, am not receiving any email  ????

Comment: Add `echo $this->email->print_debugger();` after you call `$this->email->send()` to see if any errors are occurring.

Comment: well yeah its received now, but received as text no as html ??

Comment: As per the user guide (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html) you need to set the `mailtype` to `HTML`.